# azure function triggers azure blob storage

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

i need to write an azure function in nodejs that compress any files uploaded in the azure blob storage.
i have this piece of code that does the job

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const fs = require('fs');

const def = zlib.createDeflate();

input = fs.createReadStream('file.json')
output = fs.createWriteStream('file-def.json')

input.pipe(def).pipe(output)

the azure function
```

the definition of the nodejs function is this

```
module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {
```

where myBlob contains the content of the file.

now the compression use the stream

how can I convert the file content into a stream and save the converted file that in the script above is the output variable as a new file in the blob storage but in another container?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript and Java functions load the entire blob into memory which can be accessed using context.bindings.*Name*. (Where *Name* is the input binding name as specified in the function.json file. )

For more details, please check [Azure Blob storage trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#concurrency-and-memory-usage)

Since the string/content is already in memory, a stream would not be necessary to work with `zlib`. The below code snippet uses the `deflateSync` method from `zlib` to perform the compression.

```
var input = context.bindings.myBlob;
    
var inputBuffer = Buffer.from(input);
var deflatedOutput = zlib.deflateSync(inputBuffer);

//the output can be then made available to output binding
context.bindings.myOutputBlob = deflatedOutput;
```

You can refer to the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/500368/index.html) for discussion on this topic.